# Linear algebra axler 8.c.16

Tags: linear-algebra, adjoint-operators, minimal-polynomials

> Suppose $V$ is an inner product space and $T$ $\in \mathcal L(V)$. Suppose $$a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+\cdots+a_{m-1}z^{m-1}+z^m$$ is the minimal polynomial of $T$. Prove that$$\overline{a_0}+\overline{a_1}z+\overline{a_2}z^2+\cdots+\overline{a_{m-1}}z^{m-1}+z^m$$is the minimal polynomial of $T^*$.

Since the first polynomial is a minimal polynomial, we have$$a_0+a_1T+a_2T^2+\cdots+a_{m-1}T^{m-1}+T^m=0$$ I try to use the fact that $M(T)=(\overline{M(T^*)})^t$.

Can anyone give me a hint or tell me what should I consider next? I am stuck here..

Comment: What you've written isn't exactly correct. We have $M(T)^*=\overline{M}(T^*)$ ($\overline{M}(z)$ is the polynomial whose $i$th coefficient is the complex conjugate of the $i$th coefficient of $M(z)$). Then recall that the minimal polynomial of $A$ is by definition (or by theorem) the unique irreducible monic polynomial satisfying $p(A)=0$.

Comment: Oh.. yes the fact I stated previously is wrong actually. I don't understand what you mean by $M(z)$. What my $M$ means matrix representation of $T$

Comment: Ah, I see. Then what I meant to write was $p(T)^*=\overline{p}(T^*)$ (and the same is true even if you replace $T$ with $M(T)$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that the *minimal polynomial* of $X\in\mathcal L(V)$ is the monic
polynomial $\mu_X(t)$ of least degree that annihilates $X$.

Also recall that the computation 
$$
\overline{p}(X)
= \overline{a_0}I+\overline{a_1} X+\dotsb+\overline{a_n}X^n
= (a_0I+a_1X^*+\dotsb+a_n(X^*)^n)^* 
= p(X^*)^*
$$
proves that $\overline{p}(X)=p(X^*)^*$ for any $X\in\mathcal L(V)$ and any
polynomial $p(t)$.

Now, you wish to show that $\mu_{T^*}(t)=\overline{\mu_T}(t)$. To do so, suppose
$p(t)$ annihilates $T^*$. Then
$$
\overline{p}(T)=p(T^*)^*=0^*=0
$$
so $\mu_T(t)$ divides $\overline{p}(t)$. It follows that $\overline{\mu_T}(t)$
divides $p(t)$.

That is, $\overline{\mu_T}(t)$ is a monic polynomial that annihilates $T^*$ and
divides every other polynomial that annihilates $T^*$. Hence
$\mu_{T^*}(t)=\overline{\mu_T}(t)$ as desired.

Comment: I'm wondering why $\bar{a_1}X=(a_1X^*)^*$ ?

Comment: @SeanZhou An important property of adjoints is that $(\lambda T)^*=\overline{\lambda}T^*$